# Ctrl-C and ctrl-4 do not work after openvt

Tags: linux, bash, shell, tty

I am trying to start bash with `openvt` from init system.
For this I wrote the following script

```
#!/bin/bash
openvt -c 8 -- /bin/bash
```

It starts and runs, but the Ctrl-C and Ctrl-4 shortcuts don't work. Ctrl-D, Ctrl-S and Ctrl-Q work fine. I also noticed that if I run this script manually from the terminal, it works without problems, but if I run it from another script in background (&), the described problem occurs.

In general, my task is to run an arbitrary program on a free tty. In this example, I've kept the code to a minimum to make the problem more specific.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `stty sane` to the script before running `openvt`.  For example:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
stty sane
openvt -c 8 -- /bin/bash
```

If that doesn't work, try writing a wrapper script to run with `openvt` instead of running `/bin/bash` directly.  The wrapper would be something like:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
stty sane
exec bash
```

Save it as something like `/usr/local/bin/stty-sane-bash`, make sure it's executable (with `chmod +x`), and then get your openvt script to run it instead of /bin/bash.

See `man stty` for details, but this will set the tty settings to "sane" values.

Comment: This didn't solve the problem. TTY opens but ctrl-c ctrl-4 still doesn't work.

Comment: Then the problem is in how your init systems sets up ttys. (if it does that at all - it may not do anything to set them up)  You'll need to research they what, how, and why of that - this is behaviour that is specific to the init you are running.

Comment: I have a feeling it has something to do with "controlling terminal". Very similar symptoms, only I'm not completely sure about it.

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be a way to run background tasks correctly. The only way that works is to run openvt in the foreground without the -w option.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).